# Results of p.adjust formula

Tags: r

Someone knows why data of this formula are changing each time when I using the same numbers? (please, look results for 0.724 and for 0.000155)

```
> p.adjust(c(0.724), method="bonferroni")
[1] 0.724
> p.adjust(c(0.000155), method="bonferroni")
[1] 0.000155
> p.adjust(c(0.000155, 0.868071), method="bonferroni")
[1] 0.00031 1.00000
> p.adjust(c(0.000155, 0.868071, 0.724922, 0.906480), method="bonferroni")
[1] 0.00062 1.00000 1.00000 1.00000
```

Comment: From what I see, it seems `p.adjust` is doing exactly what it is suppose to do..? Bonferroni correction is `(raw p value) * n`, where n is the number of tests you are performing. In the 1st and 2nd cases, you are performing only one test, so adjusted p value remains the same. In the 3rd case, you have two tests, so your raw p values are multiplied by `2`, and in the 4th case, you have four tests, hence the raw p values are multiplied by `4`.

Comment: Thank you very much David. So, if I have several tests to do (for instance 4), to avoid so high data, I should include only two tests each time?. What is your advices.

Comment: No, you'll need to include all the tests (i.e. comparisons) you are performing. You should read up about multiple comparisons https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem and http://stats.stackexchange.com/ is perhaps a better place to ask questions about this.